# An empty line before h1

Tags: html, css

I think it's a really simple CSS problem, but I just don't know how to solve it.

Why is there an empty line before <h1>, and how to remove it (without setting margin and line-height if possible)? Thank you!

```
<style>
.box-green { background-color: #CCC; }
.box-empty { height: 50px; }
</style>

<div class="box-empty box-green"></div>
<div class="box-green">
    <h1>There is an empty line before h1, why?</h1>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Result: http://tinkerbin.com/u6eB0PFQ

Comment: Add a working code output or fiddle

Comment: The code I posted is working, just copy & paste. Fiddle does not show the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The break is there because you are using block elements. An empty <div> element will otherwise cause a line break. You can avoid this by putting `display:inline-block;` in the CSS for the divs.

Comment: But after adding that, there is some white spaces after the line.

Comment: Then specify an exact width. If you do not define every variable you want to control, then the browser will almost definitely not give you what you want. You need to specify every variable that you want to behave a certain way. Add `width:400px;` or whatever width you want to the CSS for the div.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `display: inline` to your div to solve this.

See: http://tinkerbin.com/HDmlrG6u